# How to get T type in parent class after extends?

Tags: java

How to get T type after extends?

The code below.

```java
class A<T>{
  void method(){
    // how to get T type ?
  }
}

class B extends A<String> {
}

class C extends B {
}

class D<T> extends A<List<T>>{

}

class E extends D<String>{
}

class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    C c = new C();
    c.method();// I want to get T type here is String.
    E e = new E();
    e.method();// I want to get T type here is List<String> but I can only get String.
  }
}
```

If I create a B, I can use **getGenericSupperclass** to get T, but when I create a C, I can't.

Comment: Your class C has no generic Type, so you can't get it.

Comment: @UweAllner is there a way to get ?

Comment: When you create a C, no generic type is chosen. Your class hierarchy does not allow that, as you define a B without generics as the superclass of C.

Comment: @UweAllner So the only way I can get the T type is to inject the T class?

Comment: Within your A class you need in some way an object of the generic type. You could pass it to the constructor or create an abstract method that returns it. You then call `myObjectOfTypeT.getClass().getName()`.

Comment: @RobertKock Can you just show the code? I can't get your idea.

Answer (score 4):

You should either pass an object of the generic type with the constructor of your `A` or create an abstract method that returns an object.
Then, your `method` uses the object to get the class.

Passing an object with the constructor:

```
class A<T>{

  private T dummy;

  public A(T dummy){
    this.dummy = dummy;
  }

  void method(){
    System.out.println("Our type T is a " + dummy.getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

Using an abstract method:

```
abstract class A<T>{

  public abstract T getDummy();

  void method(){
    System.out.println("Our type T is a " + getDummy().getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

Instead of an instance of `T` the various solutions could also pass the class of T.
For instance:

```
abstract class A<T>{

  public abstract Class<T> getGenericClass();

  void method(){
    System.out.println("Our type T is a " + getGenericClass().getName());
  }
}
```

Personally, I prefer this solution.

Of course, al derived classes should be adapted.
For instance:

```
class B extends A<String> {

  @Override
  public Class<String> getGenericClass(){
    return String.class;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not.

This problem is caused by something called [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means that Java doesn't store any information about class' generics at runtime, and therefore there is no way to acquire them.

One possibility to work-around this is adding a constructor to `A` which takes a parameter of type [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) and passing the class explicitly by the extending class:

```java
class B extends A<String> {
    public B() {
        super(B.class)
    }
}
```